# Error al implementar una función "bool" de sobrecarga de operadores utilizando puntero

Tags: c++

Al implementar la siguiente función:

```
bool operator> (FiguraGeometrica *){
    return this->area() < FiguraGeometrica::area();
}
```

Recibo el siguiente error:

```
'bool operator>(FiguraGeometrica*)' must have an argument of class or enumerated type
 bool operator> (FiguraGeometrica *){
```

¿Cómo debería ser la función para poder comparar un objeto con otro mediante puntero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu función acepta un puntero como argumento:

```
bool operator> (FiguraGeometrica *){
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

... pero no le has dado un nombre a ese puntero y, por tanto, no puedes usarlo ni acceder al mismo dentro de la función.

Tienes que darle un nombre al puntero:

```
bool operator> (FiguraGeometrica * ptr){
    return this->area() < ptr->area();
}
```

Piensa que la función `area()` no es estática, por lo que necesitas una instancia del objeto para poder llamar a dicha función.

Todo esto, claro, asumiendo que la función la estás implementando en la declaración de la clase:

```
class FiguraGeometrica
{
  // ...

  bool operator>(FiguraGeometrica * ptr)
  {
    // ...
  }
};
```

Ya que si lo declaras fuera tendrás que añadir el ámbito correspondiente a la función:

```
class FiguraGeometrica
{
  // ...

  bool operator>(FiguraGeometrica * ptr); // Declaración
};

// Implementación
bool FiguraGeometrica::operator>(FiguraGeometrica * ptr)
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Importante!!!
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Estoy empezando a moverme con c++ y olvidé añadir el ámbito correspondiente, muchas gracias